# Updating a value in table with sumbit form php

Tags: php, html, mysql

My project is: i have a value (integer) in my database which in default is 0 and i want it to be updated ( I mean not to be changed, but to be added on it ) whenever a user click the submit form on my html page.
Explain further : for example my default is 0 , then 1st guest submit value=20 and it changes to 20, then saved in database. next guest submits value=30, table valu changes to 20+30=50.

my html so far :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="generator" content="3.2.2.183"/>
<title>Help The World</title>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<!-- Other scripts -->
<script src="java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td> <input name="help_1" value="25" type="checkbox" id="help_1" onclick="UpdateCost();"> </td>
<td> ResponseOption_1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input name="help_2" value="15" type="checkbox" id="help_2" onclick="UpdateCost();"> </td>
<td> ResponseOption_2 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="totalpoints" name="total" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Help World">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateCost() {
  var sum = 0;
  var gn, elem;
  for (i=1; i<3; i++) {
    gn = 'help_'+i;
    elem = document.getElementById(gn);
    if (elem. checked == true) { sum += Number(elem. value); }
  }
  document.getElementById('totalpoints' ).value = sum;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my php so far:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE total SET points= ?");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Does this table contain only a single row? How do you determine which record's `points` field should be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need the database connection details. In other words, the hostname, (often it's 'localhost'), the database name, the username for the database, and the password.

Then you need to set up a table in that database. Given your PHP above, the table name seems to be "total".

In your table "total", you need to insert a row. You could do so by running a query like this:

```
<?
// 1. here you need to insert code that connects to the database.
//...
// 2. now for the rest of the code...
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO total (id, points) values (1, 0)");
?>
```

You will only run the above line once. After that, you no longer need to run it at all, you can delete the file that you ran it with.

In the PHP file you showed above, you need to do this:

```
<?
// 1. here you need to insert code that connects to the database.
//...
// 2. now for the rest of the code...
$result_set = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT points FROM total WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch($result_set);
$old_total = $row['total'];
$new_total = $old_total + $_REQUEST['total'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE total SET points = $new_total WHERE id = 1");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, This work seems to be the thing i want as i read through it.
I created the table, i created the row, inserted the values as stated.But when i run the second code now, its gives this error:  
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch() in --- line 10   *Btw, i used this code for connection to my database : 
`$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db_name");`

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it with a bit of editing , Final Code is:

```
$result_set = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT points FROM total WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
$old_total = $row['points'];
$new_total = $old_total + $_REQUEST['total'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE total SET points = $new_total WHERE id = 1");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Big Thanks to Jodes ;)